# Code Compiler - How to compile the ASM code?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, converters, executable

I have been making a programming language compiler in C++, which converts my code to Assembly. However, I do not know how to the convert this assembly code into an executable format (.exe preferably). How would I be able to do that?

Comment: You need an assembler for your target processor, and likely a linker.  `gas` and `ld` are part of GNU binutils and freely available under the GPL, so you might start there.

Comment: You know how to write assembler output from C++ but you don`t know how to assemble it to an executable??? And if that is the case, how should we know which type of asm flavour your compiler is generating?

Comment: May be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384871/building-an-assembler

Comment: For a better answer post some output from your "compiler" as an example, and specify exactly what the development host OS and target architecture and/or OS are.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Microsoft Macro Assembler 8.0 (MASM) Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7A1C9DA0-0510-44A2-B042-7EF370530C64&displaylang=en)

The Microsoft Macro Assembler 8.0 (MASM) is a tool that consumes x86 assembly language programs and generates corresponding binaries.

Comment: This answer assumes that the output is Intel syntax x86 assembler, the development host is Windows, and that the target is either MS-DOS or Windows. That's a lot of assumptions; though possibly reasonable given the request to output a ".exe", but that assumes again that the OP knows what he is talking about - which is by no means a given.

Answer (score 0):

You *assemble* assembly code rather than *compile* it, and an assembler is the tool you need for that.

The exact assembler that you will need will depend on the target instruction set - assembly language is not in fact *a language*, it describes *any language* where mnemonics are used to represent individual machine code instructions.

Even for a single architecture, assembly language syntax may vary - for example on x86 there are at least two syntaxes - [Intel and AT&T](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html#Syntax), so even for x86 you will need an assembler that copes with whatever syntax your tool outputs.  Your tool will of course need to output something that can be used by the assembler, which may mean the generation of additional assembler and target specific directives rather than just the raw assembler mnemonics.

It may have been simpler for your language compiler to output C or C++ code (strictly a *translator* rather than a compiler), that is how early C++ "compilers" worked (and Comeau C++ still does), your language will then at least be more easily portable between different architectures.  C compilers are almost as ubiquitous as assemblers for any target, but translation to C allows you to have a single back-end for all target architectures.